# Is there a simple graph with five vertices of degrees 1, 2, 3, 4, 4?

Tags: graph-theory

This sum is even (14), but can not find the graph. because it does not exist?

Comment: Can you draw a graph with degree sequence 1,2,3 ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If two vertices have degree 4, can any vertex have degree 1?

More generally, the [Havel-Hakimi Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) decides when a given sequence of numbers is realized by a graph.

Comment: "If two vertices have degree 4, can any vertex have degree 1?" I dont know. An another rule for graph validate is has an even number of odd degree vertices (1, 3).

Comment: Just try and draw it. The two 4 degree vertices will have to be connected to every other vertex. Which means every vertex is connected to atleast these two vertices of degree four. So every vertex has to have degree at least 2.

Comment: ah! really! now I understood, thank you =)